# Open a modal before sending form-data Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, action

I am trying to present the user with a *terms and conditions* modal before registering them.

**Blade**

```
<form method="POST" autocomplete="signupForm-noFill" action={{url("/register")}}>
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div class="form-group text-center signupForm">
        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control text-center loginForm" id="signup-email" autocomplete="no-Thanks" placeholder="Email Address">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group text-center signupForm">
        <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control text-center loginForm" id="signup-password" autocomplete="please-No" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group text-center" style="display:inline-block; margin-bottom:20px;">
    {!! Recaptcha::render() !!}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group text-center" style="">
        <button type="submit" id="registerButton" role="button" class="btn btn-hp-modal btn-signup">Sign up</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('#registerButton').click(function() {
    $("#legalModal").modal("show");
    return false; 
});

$('#acceptTerms').click(function() {
    // Submit form data to {{url("/register")}}  
    return false; 
});
```

**Modal Button**

```
<button type="submit" id="acceptTerms" class="btn btn-hp-modal underline btn-signup-modal">I Accept</button>
```

The issue is that I am not sure how to go back to the form's `action` and submit its data.

I tried passing the variables to the `JavaScript` functions but I can't seem to have it submit to the actual `controller`.

**Edit**

`<button type="submit" id="acceptTerms" class="btn btn-hp-modal underline btn-signup-modal">I Accept</button>`

Answer (score 1):

You just need to submit the form using js

**Blade:**

```
<form id="my_form" method="POST" autocomplete="signupForm-noFill" action={{url("/register")}}>
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div class="form-group text-center signupForm">
        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control text-center loginForm" id="signup-email" autocomplete="no-Thanks" placeholder="Email Address">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group text-center signupForm">
        <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control text-center loginForm" id="signup-password" autocomplete="please-No" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group text-center" style="display:inline-block; margin-bottom:20px;">
    {!! Recaptcha::render() !!}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group text-center" style="">
        <button type="submit" id="registerButton" role="button" class="btn btn-hp-modal btn-signup">Sign up</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

**JS:**

```
$('#registerButton').click(function() {
    $("#legalModal").modal("show");
    return false; 
});

$('#acceptTerms').click(function() {
    $('#my_form').submit(); 
});
```

Comment: When I added it, I am being directed back to the initial page `/signup?` when I accept the terms. I added the `modal` button to my question.